# Mark Outgoing API Calls as Child Calls

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

How can I **mark outgoing API calls as child** from the incoming call that triggered them. (assuming `$request->Input('CallSid')` is the `CallSid` of the incoming call)

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from https://twilio.com/docs/libraries/php
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php'; // Loads the library
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "AC6ad3d3d3f5ed08ebf2b662cae36b4d32";
$token = "your_auth_token";
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$call = $client->calls->create(
    "+14155551212", "+14158675310",
    array("url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml")
);

echo $call->sid;
```

*from https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls*

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here. What is the call flow you are creating? Child calls are created when one call uses TwiML to make outgoing calls via `<Dial>`, what are you trying to do?

Comment: A incoming call creates several outgoing API calls, I wondering how to manage them as child calls (would it be easier to manage in the interface or directly in code.. for now, I have to save IDs in session in order to retrieve them afterward..) In other words question would be, __is it possible to configure `ParentCallSid` field when creating a new API Call ?__

Comment: I've answered, because that isn't possible. I'm just interested in what you're really trying to achieve here. Can you explain your call flow a bit more? Or why you need these API generated calls to refer back to the original call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It is not possible to set the `ParentCallSid` attribute of a call via the API. `ParentCallSid` is set when a call is generated in TwiML, usually with [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial), as part of another call.

When you create a call from the REST API that call has no parent.